# Fortran convert string to number

Tags: class, fortran

I want to have a subroutine that converts a contents of a numeric
string to a numeric type (int, real, double precision, real(real128)).

However I am getting an error when trying to use `Class(*)`. The error
is shown below:

```
gfortran -o build/lib/larsa.o -c -ffree-form -g -J./build/lib lib/larsa.f
lib/larsa.f:1933.35:

 Read (s, frmt, iostat=ios) num
                               1
Error: Data transfer element at (1) cannot be polymorphic unless 
it is processed by a defined     input/output procedure
lib/larsa.f:1935.32:

 Read (s, *, iostat=ios) num
                            1
Error: Data transfer element at (1) cannot be polymorphic unless 
it is processed by a defined input/output procedure
```

This is the subroutine I have written.

```
Subroutine converts_str_to_num  &
  (                             &
    s, num,                     &
    fmt, wrn                    &
  )

Character (len=*), Intent (in) :: s
Character (len=*), Intent (in), Optional :: fmt 

Class (*) :: num
Character (len=*), Intent (inout), Optional :: wrn 

Integer :: ios
Character (len=65) :: frmt

!!$ Reads contents of s and puts value in i.

If (Present (fmt)) Then
  frmt = "(" // Trim (fmt) //  ")"
  Read (s, frmt, iostat=ios) num
Else
  Read (s, *, iostat=ios) num
End If

End Subroutine converts_str_to_num
```

Comment: What is your question?  The error message is quite clear: you can't use a polymorphic variable in an I/O list unless it's using defined I/O.  Are you after "what does that mean?"?

Comment: Is there a workaround and still have `Class (*)` in there?

Comment: @ChristopherDimech yes, use a `select type` construct and write a case for all types you wish to handle.

Comment: @ChristopherDimech based on this and your other questions you might benefit from reading a book such as Modern Fortarn Explained (Metcalf, Reid and Cohen) http://www.amazon.com/Explained-Numerical-Mathematics-Scientific-Computation/dp/0199601429

Comment: I do not undertand how it works when I use `select type`. I still use num insode the `type is` and doing that the compiler does not complain.

Comment: Inside the `type is` the variable is not polymorphic (if you mean `select type (num)`).  Metcalf _et al._ will indeed be a better bet than answers here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To tidy up the comments, I'll provide an answer.

The error message is clear: you cannot have a polymorphic variable in an input/output list unless the list is processed by defined input/output.  This is 9.6.3.5 in Fortran 2008.  `class(*) num` is (unlimited) polymorphic.

Now, for polymorphic derived types you could define such a defined input/output procedure, but that counts as a lot of work and gfortran certainly doesn't (yet) support that notion.  Also, you can't do this for intrinsic types.  These factors mean you have to deal with non-polymorphic variables in the input list you have.

Of course, it's possible to use generics to avoid polymorphism, but the alternative (as it is for about everything polymorphic) is to use a `select type` construct.  For simplicity, ignore the list-directed and explicit format cases:

```
select type (assoc => num)
type is (int)
   Read (s, *, iostat=ios) assoc
type is (real)
   ...
type is (...)
class default
   error stop "Oh noes!"
end select
```

I've used an associate name in the select type to address one part of your confusion.  If you've just done

```
select type(num)
type is (int)
  Read (s, *, iostat=ios) num
end select
```

to think that "now using `num` is fine: why?" that's because the `num` inside the construct is not the same as the `num` outside.  Crucially, it isn't polymorphic but is the exact type matching the `type is`.